# PySpark read hadoop-snappy compressed JSON

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

**Objective**

Read hadoop-snappy compressed JSON with PySpark.

**Environment**

MacBook Pro with M1, Python 3.9.5, PySpark 3.2.2

**Steps to reproduce**

- Install PySpark

```bash
pip install pyspark==3.2.2
```

- Write simple PySpark code in order to read from S3 an hadoop-snappy compressed JSON

```py
# app.py

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

data_frame = spark.read.json("file:///path/to/file.json.snappy")

data_frame.show()
```

- Execute

```bash
python app.py
```

**Output**

```
22/08/09 12:52:01 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)/ 1]
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'int org.apache.hadoop.shaded.org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.rawUncompress(java.nio.ByteBuffer, int, int, java.nio.ByteBuffer, int)'
        at org.apache.hadoop.shaded.org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.rawUncompress(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.shaded.org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.uncompress(Snappy.java:551)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappy.SnappyDecompressor.decompressDirectBuf(SnappyDecompressor.java:267)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappy.SnappyDecompressor.decompress(SnappyDecompressor.java:217)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BlockDecompressorStream.decompress(BlockDecompressorStream.java:88)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.read(DecompressorStream.java:105)
        at java.base/java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:205)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.fillBuffer(LineReader.java:191)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:227)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:185)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.skipUtfByteOrderMark(LineRecordReader.java:158)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.nextKeyValue(LineRecordReader.java:198)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.HadoopFileLinesReader.hasNext(HadoopFileLinesReader.scala:69)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:191)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:104)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.isEmpty(Iterator.scala:387)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.isEmpty$(Iterator.scala:387)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.isEmpty(Iterator.scala:1431)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.reduceLeftOption(TraversableOnce.scala:249)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.reduceLeftOption$(TraversableOnce.scala:248)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.reduceLeftOption(Iterator.scala:1431)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.reduceOption(TraversableOnce.scala:256)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.reduceOption$(TraversableOnce.scala:256)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.reduceOption(Iterator.scala:1431)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema.$anonfun$infer$1(JsonInferSchema.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2(RDD.scala:863)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2$adapted(RDD.scala:863)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1491)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
22/08/09 12:52:01 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (192.168.1.43 executor driver): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'int org.apache.hadoop.shaded.org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.rawUncompress(java.nio.ByteBuffer, int, int, java.nio.ByteBuffer, int)'
        at org.apache.hadoop.shaded.org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.rawUncompress(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.shaded.org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.uncompress(Snappy.java:551)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappy.SnappyDecompressor.decompressDirectBuf(SnappyDecompressor.java:267)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappy.SnappyDecompressor.decompress(SnappyDecompressor.java:217)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BlockDecompressorStream.decompress(BlockDecompressorStream.java:88)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.read(DecompressorStream.java:105)
        at java.base/java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:205)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.fillBuffer(LineReader.java:191)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:227)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:185)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.skipUtfByteOrderMark(LineRecordReader.java:158)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.nextKeyValue(LineRecordReader.java:198)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.HadoopFileLinesReader.hasNext(HadoopFileLinesReader.scala:69)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:191)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:104)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.isEmpty(Iterator.scala:387)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.isEmpty$(Iterator.scala:387)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.isEmpty(Iterator.scala:1431)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.reduceLeftOption(TraversableOnce.scala:249)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.reduceLeftOption$(TraversableOnce.scala:248)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.reduceLeftOption(Iterator.scala:1431)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.reduceOption(TraversableOnce.scala:256)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.reduceOption$(TraversableOnce.scala:256)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.reduceOption(Iterator.scala:1431)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema.$anonfun$infer$1(JsonInferSchema.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2(RDD.scala:863)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2$adapted(RDD.scala:863)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1491)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

**Expected**

I expect to see the resulting data frame.

What am I missing? Do I have to install Hadoop or is it possible to make this work without it?

Answer (score 0):

When you get the error `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`, I think that the snappy jar is not found in your spark cluster (which is very strange), try to download it when you create the session:

```py
spark = (
    SparkSession.builder
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:1.1.8.4")
    .getOrCreate()
)
```

Comment: Even if I add that jar, I get the exact same error...